# Viewing PDF in IE, hitting back navigates back 2 pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

Somewhat new to asp.net using c#.  On my site, users have the option to view a pdf in the browser window.  The pdf data is stored in an SQL database and I use the following code:

```
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["ContentData"];
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + dt.Rows[0]    ["FileName"].ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

The issue I am having only in Internet Explorer is when the user hits the back button, it navigates back 2 pages.  It's not critical, but annoying to the users.  I apologize if this has been asked, but I was having trouble coming up with search terms to find the issue.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

csnewbie

Comment: I think this issue is actually related to the PDF Viewer working differently as an IE addon. It's one of the downsides to compatability unfortunately. There is probably a way to solve it, but I suspect that it's considering each 2 pages to be 1 "page", like a "side by side" viewer, which would actually display two pages at once (a left and a right page, like a real book)...

Comment: I had a feeling it was something along those lines.  Thanks for the response!